# page alignment and div element alignment

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-bootstrap

So I am trying to build a page like this :

[image]

but it looks like this:

[image]

I try to use multiple `div` and also combine `Row` and `Col` to do it but it seems a mess. Some changes also do not have any effects.

Code:

```
import React from 'react';
import TextContents from '../assets/translations/TextContents';
import BlueButton from '../components/materialdesign/BlueButton';
import TeachIcon from '../assets/images/teach-class-icon.svg';
import HostIcon from '../assets/images/host-a-class-icon.svg';

import './CreateClassAndHost.css';
import { Row, Col, Container } from 'react-bootstrap';

class CreateClassAndHost extends React.Component {

    render() {

        const CreateAClass = 
            <Col className="create-tile">
                <div className="create-style-title">
                    <img
                        src= { TeachIcon }
                        className= "create-icon"
                        alt="TeachIcon"
                    />    
                    <h2>{TextContents.BeATeacher}</h2>
                </div>
                <p>{TextContents.BeATeacherDesc}</p>
                <div className="create-button">
                <BlueButton textSize="13" link_href="/createaclass" text={TextContents.BeATeacherBtn} />
                </div>
            </Col>;

        const CreateAHost = 
            <Col className="create-tile">
                <div className="create-style-title">
                    <img
                        src= { HostIcon }
                        className= "create-icon"
                        alt="HostIcon"
                    />  
                    <h2>{TextContents.HostAClass}</h2>
                </div>
                <p>{TextContents.HostAClassDesc}</p>
                <div className="create-button">
                <BlueButton textSize="13" link_href="/createahost" text={TextContents.HostAClassBtn} />
                </div>
            </Col>;
        return (
            <Container bsPrefix="create-container">
                <h1>{TextContents.CreateClassOrHostTitle}</h1>
                <Row classname="create-section">
                    {CreateAClass}
                    {CreateAHost}
                </Row>
            </Container>

        );
    }

}

export default CreateClassAndHost;
```

Css code :

```
.create-container {
    margin-top: 8%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 60%;
}

.create-container h1 {
    text-align: center;
    height: 51px;
    margin: auto;
    font-family: Fredoka One;
    font-size: 50px;
    color: #333333;
    width:100%;
}

.create-section {
    width:100%;
}

.create-icon {
    width:47px;
    height:47px ;
}

.create-style-title {

}

.create-tile {
    display: inline-block;
    left: 12px;
    top: 80px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 200px;
    height: 250px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}


.create-tile h2 {
    font-family: Source Sans Pro;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 30px;
    line-height: 0.7;
    color: #333333;
    letter-spacing: -0.6px;

}

.create-tile p {
    font-family: Source Sans Pro;
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 1.6;
    color: #616161;
    width: 280px;
    height: 85px; 
}

.create-button {
    position: relative;
    left: 0px;
    top: 50px;
}
```

Any idea how to make it looks like the page provide above ?

Also anyone can provide a good resources on how to build properly layout. I would like to also looke at myself on some resource easily showing how to align,.. build...

Thanks

Comment: for resources I would look at css grid https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout or flexbox, this is a fun game to play to learn it: https://flexboxfroggy.com/

Comment: also if you create a sandbox, can help you :) just haven't used bootstrap before so off the top of my head im not sure

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I would simplify the structure before anything else. Then I would use the `:before` selector to insert the being icons and set `text-align` property value for the parent element to `center`, set a `fixed` `width` for the child elements.

```css
#parent {
  text-align: center;
}

.card {
  width: 200px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 25px;
}

a {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 36px;
  line-height: 36px;
  font-size: 17px;
  background: blue;
  margin-top: 25px;
  color: white;
  padding: 0 20px;
  border-radius: 36px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

h2 {
  position: relative; /* To help control overlap */
}

h2:before {
  content: "accessible_forward"; /* You can also use images as the content */
  font-family: Material Icons;
  position: relative;
  flort: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.card:nth-of-type(2) h2:before {
  content: "anchor";
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
<div id="parent">

  <div class="card">
    <h2>Titlt1</h2>
    <p>
      "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip
    </p>

    <a hred="#">Click me</a>
  </div>

  <div class="card">
    <h2>Titlt2</h2>
    <p>
      "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip
    </p>
    <a hred="#">Click me</a>
  </div>

</div>
```